# Duplication Issue In Wordpress Loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a website now. I'm creating a team page that will show the team members posted from the admin backend. I created a loop successfully for that. Also I created custom fields for telephone, name and more. I posted the first team member leaving the telephone field blank, then i posted the second team member filling out the telephone field. To my surprise, the telephone number I filled in for the second team member shows up in the first. This applies for other fields too if left blank. I have searched and tried so many solutions online but they don't work. I will appreciate a candid review of my code here below:

```
<?php
  $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'specialist') );
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; //This is the magic line

     $meta = get_post_custom();
      if($meta['full_name'][0]) {
       $name = $meta['full_name'][0];
      }

      if($meta['designation'][0]) {
       $title = $meta['designation'][0];
      }

      if($meta['email_address'][0]) {
       $mail = $meta['email_address'][0];
      }

      if($meta['facebook'][0]) {
       $fb = $meta['facebook'][0];
      }

      if($meta['twitter'][0]) {
       $tw = $meta['twitter'][0];
      }

      if($meta['gplus'][0]) {
       $googlep = $meta['gplus'][0];
      }

      if($meta['telephone_no'][0]) {
       $tel = $meta['telephone_no'][0];
      }
  ?>
  <div class="grid_4">

    <div class="team-img-big">
      <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>" data-imagelightbox="a"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class' => 'team-pix-big') ); ?></a>
    </div>

    <p class="team-name"><?php echo($name); ?></p>
    <p class="team-designation"><?php echo($title); ?></p>
    <p class="team-tel"><span class="fa fa-phone" style="padding-right:5px"></span><?php echo($tel); ?></p>


      <?php the_content() ?>

      <div class="team-social-big">
      <a href="<?php echo ($fb);?>"><span class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="padding-left:5px"></span></a>
      <a href="<?php echo($tw); ?>"><span class="fa fa-twitter-square" style="padding-left:5px"></span></a>
      <a href="<?php echo($googlep);?>"><span class="fa fa-google-plus-square" style="padding-left:5px"></span></a>
      <a href="mailto:<?php echo($mail);?>"><span class="fa fa-envelope" style="padding-left:5px"></span></a>
      </div>

  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php   wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Below is my screenshot for clarification
[image]

The phone number is meant to show only in the second post not both

Comment: define all the variables empty before loop so like `$tel = '';`

Comment: You have a bug in `get_post_custom();` - what does that function do?

Comment: @Noman using `$tel = '';` left the telephone fields empty for both. I defined it before the loop but it doesn't work

Comment: Define all variables empty *within* the loop, at the begining, so that if loop's result is empty it won't keep the previous value

Comment: @doublesharp  `get_post_custom();` is not a bug, it's for the custom fields already registered.

Comment: You have undefined variables in your loop if a field is left open. This causes unexpected results

Comment: @PieterGoosen Please can you explain better? Sorry I'm  a newbie in programming

Comment: @Sam - I could tell that, but since you're issue is with it setting (or fetching?) the wrong value, my guess is that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated, you have a couple of bugs in your code in the form of undefined variables when a field is empty or not set (*which also is a bug on its own*). This will cause unexpected output as you have seen.

- Invoke the `$post` global to be safe

You would want to do the following here

- Sanitize and validate a field. This is **EXTREMELY IMPORTANT**. Never ever leave any backdoors in your code. You **MUST** always always sanitize any user submitted info (*like `$_GET`, `$_POST` and form field data*). Not doing this can lead to malicious cod beign injected into your site. Not sanitizing data is the number one reason for hacked sites
- Set up your variable with a default value which will be used if a condition fails. Always code with a midset that your code **will** fail. This way, you eliminate bugs

So lets look at how your code should look like

```
// Invoke the $post global
global $post;

// Get the post meta for the particular post
$meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID );

// Now we can get our values, sanitize them and set defaults
// $variable_name = (check if field isset) ? (sanitize field because it exist) : (set default, field does not exist);
$name  = isset( $meta['full_name'][0] )     ? filter_var( $meta['full_name'][0],     FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : '';
$title = isset( $meta['designation'][0] )   ? filter_var( $meta['designation'][0],   FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ) : '';
$mail  = isset( $meta['email_address'][0] ) ? filter_var( $meta['email_address'][0], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL  ) : '';    
// etc, use the correct filter for the specific field, see http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php
```

You can now safely use your variables as they have been sanitized, validated and have a default (*which is an empty string*) should a field not be set.

Just one last note, you should use `wp_reset_postdata()` after the loop, not `wp_reset_query()`, latter is used with `query_posts` which you should never ever use

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this with @Noman suggestion to define all variables empty. Here is the adjusted code:

```
             <?php
                    $query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'specialist') );
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                    $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID; //This is the magic line

                         $meta = get_post_custom();
                          if($meta['full_name'][0]) {
                           $name = $meta['full_name'][0];
                          }

                          if($meta['designation'][0]) {
                           $title = $meta['designation'][0];
                          }

                          if($meta['email_address'][0]) {
                           $mail = $meta['email_address'][0];
                          }

                          if($meta['facebook'][0]) {
                           $fb = $meta['facebook'][0];
                          }

                          $tw = ''; //(new) declare this empty to avoid dupliaction
                          if($meta['twitter'][0]) {
                           $tw = $meta['twitter'][0];
                          }

                          if($meta['gplus'][0]) {
                           $googlep = $meta['gplus'][0];
                          }

                          $tel = ''; //declare this empty to avoid duplication
                          if($meta['telephone_no'][0]) {
                           $tel = $meta['telephone_no'][0];
                          }
                    ?>
                    <div class="grid_4">

                        <div class="team-img-big">
                          <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?>" data-imagelightbox="a"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full', array('class' => 'team-pix-big') ); ?></a>
                        </div>

                        <p class="team-name"><?php echo($name); ?></p>
                        <p class="team-designation"><?php echo($title); ?></p>
                        <p class="team-tel"><span class="fa fa-phone" style="padding-right:5px"></span><?php echo($tel); ?></p>


                          <?php the_content() ?>

                          <div class="team-social-big">
                            <a href="<?php echo ($fb);?>"><span class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="padding-left:5px"></span></a>
                            <a href="<?php echo($tw); ?>"><span class="fa fa-twitter-square" style="padding-left:5px"></span></a>
                            <a href="<?php echo($googlep);?>"><span class="fa fa-google-plus-square" style="padding-left:5px"></span></a>
                            <a href="mailto:<?php echo($mail);?>"><span class="fa fa-envelope" style="padding-left:5px"></span></a>
                          </div>

                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                    <?php   wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Thank you @Noman for the suggestion